# R - Scraping an HTML table with rvest when there are missing <tr> tags

Tags: html, r, html-table, rvest

I'm trying to scrape an HTML table from a website using rvest. The only problem is that the table I'm trying to scrape doesn't have `<tr>` tags, except on the first row. It looks like this:

```
<tr> 
  <td>6/21/2015 9:38 PM</td>
  <td>5311 Lake Park</td>
  <td>UCPD</td>
  <td>African American</td>
  <td>Male</td>
  <td>Subject was causing a disturbance in the area.</td>
  <td>Name checked; no further action</td>
  <td>No</td>
</tr>

  <td>6/21/2015 10:37 PM</td>
  <td>5200 S Blackstone</td>
  <td>UCPD</td>
  <td>African American</td>
  <td>Male</td>
  <td>Subject was observed fighting in the McDonald's parking lot</td>
  <td>Warned; released</td>
  <td>No</td>
</tr>
```

And so on. So, using the following code, I'm only able to get the first row into my data frame:

```
library(rvest)
mydata <- html_session("https://incidentreports.uchicago.edu/incidentReportArchive.php?startDate=06/01/2015&endDate=06/21/2015") %>%
    html_node("table") %>%
    html_table(header = TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

How can I alter this to get html_table to understand that the rows are rows, even if they don't have an opening `<tr>` tag? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why not first replace any closing `</tr>` by `</tr><tr>` and then remove the last trailing `<tr>`?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(rvest)

url_parse<- read_html("https://incidentreports.uchicago.edu/incidentReportArchive.php?startDate=06/01/2015&endDate=06/21/2015") 

col_name<- url_parse %>%
  html_nodes("th") %>%
  html_text()

mydata <- url_parse %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()

finaldata <- data.frame(matrix(mydata, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE))

names(finaldata) <- col_name

finaldata

                     Incident                                  Location    

    Reported                              Occurred
1                           Theft       1115 E. 58th St. (Walker Bike Rack) 6/1/15 12:18 PM 5/31/15 to 6/1/15 8:00 PM to 12:00 PM
2                     Information                          5835 S. Kimbark   6/1/15 3:57 PM                        6/1/15 3:55 PM
3                     Information                  1025 E. 58th St. (Swift)  6/2/15 2:18 AM                        6/2/15 2:18 AM
4 Non-Criminal Damage to Property                850 E. 63rd St. (Car Wash)  6/2/15 8:48 AM                        6/2/15 8:00 AM
5     Criminal Damage to Property 5631 S. Cottage Grove (Parking Structure)  6/2/15 7:32 PM             6/2/15 6:45 PM to 7:30 PM
                                                                                                                   Comments / Nature of Fire Disposition
1                                                                                       Bicycle secured to bike rack taken by unknown person        Open
2             Unknown person used staff member's personal information to file a fraudulent claim with U.S. Social Security Admin. / CPD case         CPD
3 Three unaffiliated individuals reported tampering with bicycles in bike rack / Subjects were given trespass warnings and sent on their way      Closed
4                                                                      Rear wiper blade assembly damaged on UC owned vehicle during car wash      Closed
5                                                           Unknown person(s) spray painted graffiti on north concrete wall of the structure        Open
  UCPDI#
1 E00344
2 E00345
3 E00346
4 E00347
5 E00348
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach than @user227710, but generally the same. This, similarly, exploits the fact that the number of `TD`s is uniform.

**However**, this also grabs *all* the incidents (`rbind`s each page into one `incidents` data frame).

The `pblapply` just gives you progress bars since this take a few seconds. Totally not necessary unless in an interactive session.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)

url <- "https://incidentreports.uchicago.edu/incidentReportArchive.php?startDate=06/01/2015&endDate=06/21/2015"
pg <- read_html(url)

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("li.page-count") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  str_split(" / ") %>%
  unlist %>% 
  as.numeric %>% 
  .[2] -> total_pages

pblapply(1:(total_pages), function(j) {

  # get "column names"
  # NOTE that you get legit column names for use with "regular" 
  # data frames this way

  pg %>% 
    html_nodes("thead > tr > th") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    make.names -> tcols

  # get all the TDs

  pg %>% 
    html_nodes("td") %>%
    as_list() -> tds

  # how many rows do we have? (shld be 5, but you never know)

  trows <- length(tds) / 7

  # the basic idea is to grab all the TDs for each row
  # then cbind them together and then rbind the whole thing
  # while keeping decent column names

  bind_rows(lapply(1:trows, function(i) {
    setNames(cbind.data.frame(lapply(1:7, function(j) { 
      html_text(tds[[(i-1)*7 + j]])
    }), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), tcols)
  })) -> curr_tbl

  # get next url

  pg %>% 
    html_nodes("li.next > a") %>% 
    html_attr("href") -> next_url

  if (j < total_pages) {
    pg <<- read_html(sprintf("https://incidentreports.uchicago.edu/%s", next_url))
  }

  curr_tbl

}) %>% bind_rows -> incidents

incidents

## Source: local data frame [62 x 7]
## 
##                            Incident                                  Location        Reported
## 1                             Theft       1115 E. 58th St. (Walker Bike Rack) 6/1/15 12:18 PM
## 2                       Information                          5835 S. Kimbark   6/1/15 3:57 PM
## 3                       Information                  1025 E. 58th St. (Swift)  6/2/15 2:18 AM
## 4   Non-Criminal Damage to Property                850 E. 63rd St. (Car Wash)  6/2/15 8:48 AM
## 5       Criminal Damage to Property 5631 S. Cottage Grove (Parking Structure)  6/2/15 7:32 PM
## 6  Information / Aggravated Robbery                4701 S. Ellis (Public Way)  6/3/15 2:11 AM
## 7                     Lost Property           5800 S. University  (Main Quad)  6/3/15 8:30 AM
## 8       Criminal Damage to Property         5505 S. Ellis (Parking Structure) 5/29/15 5:00 PM
## 9       Information / Armed Robbery        6300 S. Cottage Grove (Public Way)  6/3/15 2:33 PM
## 10                    Lost Property                1414 E. 59th St. (I-House)  6/3/15 2:28 PM
## ..                              ...                                       ...             ...
## Variables not shown: Occurred (chr), Comments...Nature.of.Fire (chr), Disposition (chr), UCPDI. (chr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! I ended up getting some help from another R user off line who suggested the following solution. It takes the html, saves it, adds in the `<tr>` (much like @Bram Vanroy suggested), and turns it back into an html object, which can then be scraped into a dataframe.

```
library(rvest)
myurl <- "https://incidentreports.uchicago.edu/incidentReportArchive.php?startDate=06/01/2015&endDate=06/21/2015"
download.file(myurl, destfile="myfile.html", method="curl")
myhtml <- readChar("myfile.html", file.info("myfile.html")$size)
myhtml <- gsub("</tr>", "</tr><tr>", myhtml, fixed = TRUE)
mydata <- html(myhtml)

mydf <- mydata %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

mydf <- na.omit(mydf)
```

The last line is to omit some weird NA rows that show up with this method.